# How to create a new column with case or update an old column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table googleplaystore and column Size. I had to remove the last letters from the column Size and I want to drop the old column Size and Save a new one based on case. How do you save a column from case to a new column? I also need to convert values with k (kilobytes) into MB.

```
SELECT Size,
CASE
WHEN RIGHT(Size,1) = 'k' OR RIGHT(Size,1) = 'M'  THEN SUBSTRING(Size,1,LEN(Size)-1)
ELSE 'Varies with device'
END
FROM googleplaystore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
Update googleplaystore
    set size = CASE
    WHEN RIGHT(Size,1) = 'k' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Size,1,LEN(Size)-1) as float)/ cast(1024 as float)
    WHEN RIGHT(Size,1) = 'M' THEN SUBSTRING(Size,1,LEN(Size)-1)
    ELSE size 
END 
from googleplaystore
```

to convert from kb to MB in this case you need to divide by 1024.

Input :

```
size
1000K
1000M
2000
```

Result :

```
size
0.976563
1000
2000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cj97G41S)